# Does Apache use file timestamps to check whether a resource has been modified?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, last-modified

I am developing an html page referencing a large Javascript file (1MB+) which is seldom modified. From [here](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1s7), I get that the js file will not be resent if not modified.

My question is: how does Apache checks whether an ftp uploaded javascript file has been modified? Is it from its file timestamp? If not, where does it get this information? I want to understand the process to control performance issues.

Comment: It can't be minified, but zipped, it is 301k, which is reasonable, especially if it is not resent over and over...

Comment: @alex: I have seen Google use 1MB _minified_ JavaScript.

Comment: For a complex JavaScript-based web application, 1MB is not out of line; especially considering applications like this (think stuff in the Google Apps suite) generally only use one page, dynamically updated, meaning that even without caching, a single session only means one page view and one time loading the JS.

Comment: I'm not saying that's how large Google's JS is; just that a JS-based application on that scale is likely to have what most web developers would consider to be an absurd amount of JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static files, a call to [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/stat.html) is typically used to check if the file size or modification time has changed.

The [Caching Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/caching.html) goes into detail and also contains the above reference in the section *A Brief Guide to Conditional Requests*.